# Child <div> fill remaning height of float <div> left

Tags: html, css

So in my JSFiddle, I'm trying to make the `div.content.groepsfeest` fill up the remaining height so that the bottom aligns properly with the bottom of the left `div`.

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/Rings/z4tLcvxz/

Comment: Is it ok to update the HTML a little bit, i.e. add a `<div>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that hasn't been mentioned yet is using flexbox.  You'd need to wrap your columns in a containing `div` with `display: flex` on like

```
.flex-container {
    clear: both;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then give all the columns `flex: 1`.  [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/z4tLcvxz/5/)

Comment: Great this does the tric perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Use display: 
`table-row` and `table-cell`

Like:

```
.events {
    display: table-row;
}
.events .left {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.events .right {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #ee3940;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z4tLcvxz/1/

Solution with `flex` from [Pattle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28881206/4389010) is ok but remember about some browser limitations of this method:

http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: Remember about that flex isn't supported with IE very good, but in general its awesome part of CSS3.